# Как скопировать несколько раз горизонтально svg?

Tags: css, вёрстка, svg

Имеется svg звезда для отображения рейтинга, и нужно повторить его горизонтально несколько раз.
И чтобы можно было регулировать отступы между звёздами с помощью css.
Как можно скопировать в горизонтальную линию svg с определёнными отступами?

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
<style type="text/css">
.st0{fill:#ffff00;}
</style>
<path class="st0" d="M12 .587l3.668 7.568 8.332 1.151-6.064 5.828 1.48 8.279-7.416-3.967-7.417 3.967 1.481-8.279-6.064-5.828 8.332-1.151z"/>
</svg>
```

Или хотя-бы подскажите, как можно настроить отступы в теге `path` чтобы можно было скопировать тег `path` и поставить нужный отступ?
Возможно нужно будет применять другой svg, можете подсказать, как можно копировать svg горизонтально в ряд?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для копирования элементов svg существует команда `<use>`
Для этого надо разместить элемент в секцию `<defs>` и клонировать этот элемент с помощью `<use>`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="120" height="24" viewBox="60 0 24 24" >
<style type="text/css">
.st0{fill:gold;}
</style>
<defs>
<path id="star" class="st0" d="M12 .587l3.668 7.568 8.332 1.151-6.064 5.828 1.48 8.279-7.416-3.967-7.417 3.967 1.481-8.279-6.064-5.828 8.332-1.151z"/>
</defs>
<use  xlink:href="#star" x="10" y="0"  />
 <use  xlink:href="#star" x="35" y="0"  />
   <use  xlink:href="#star" x="60" y="0"  /> 
     <use  xlink:href="#star" x="85" y="0"  />
        <use  xlink:href="#star" x="110" y="0"  />
</svg>
```

Comment: @MaximLensky что <defs>, что <symdol> работают одинаково, - сначала прячем, потом вызываем по `ID` если не влом, дай ссылку, посмотрю

Comment: @MaximLensky чуваки, читают раскрученные сайты типа css-tricks, где настоятельно рекомендуется использование SVG только, как background, а это самый плохой способ применения SVG, так как нет стилизации, интерактивности, адаптивности, кроче всех плюшек SVG зачем тогда применять SVG? Можно сразу ставить картинку на background

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, выдало ошибку, как это можно исправить? error on line 8 at column 40: Namespace prefix xlink for href on use is not defined

Comment: Добавьте в шапку svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink Сейчас дополню ответ

Comment: мне кажется здесь удобнее - я удалил всё

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, можете подсказать, я пытался применить ваш способ для другой svg, но иконки вообще нет на экране при открытии svg

Comment: @word вот на этот конкретный вопрос я ответил на 100% Но я же не телепат, откуда я могу знать, как вы там сверстали :) Задайте новый вопрос с подробным кодом и я  или кто-то другой постараюсь ответить. А вот этот ответ хорошо бы принять как решение :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, подскажите пожалуйста, 
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1110133/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-svg-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4