# При изменении кода SVG иконки её не видно при клонировании c помощью <use> из секции <defs>

Tags: css, svg

Есть svg-код иконки, нужно его скопировать горизонтально один за другим.
Как это можно сделать?  сейчас при открытии иконки на экране нет иконки.
т.е. интересует именно способ через теги svg, к примеру с помощью тега `use xlink:href`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="120" height="24" viewBox="60 0 24 24" >
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:#000000;}
</style>
<defs>
<path id="star" class="st0" d="M800,318.1C624.6,318.1,481.9,175.4,481.9,0h-30.4H348.5h-30.4c0,175.4-142.7,318.1-318.1,318.1v30.4
 c0,0,0,0,0,0v133.3c175.4,0,318.1,142.7,318.1,318.1h30.4h102.9h30.4c0-175.4,142.7-318.1,318.1-318.1v-30.4c0,0,0,0,0,0V318.1z
  M400,590.8C357.3,509.5,290.5,442.7,209.2,400c81.3-42.7,148.1-109.5,190.8-190.8c42.7,81.3,109.5,148.1,190.8,190.8
 C509.5,442.7,442.7,509.5,400,590.8z"/>
</defs>
<use  xlink:href="#star" x="10" y="0"  />
<use  xlink:href="#star" x="35" y="0"  />
</svg>
```

также как сделано здесь:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="120" height="24" viewBox="60 0 24 24" >
<style type="text/css">
.st0{fill:gold;}
</style>
<defs>
<path id="star" class="st0" d="M12 .587l3.668 7.568 8.332 1.151-6.064 5.828 1.48 8.279-7.416-3.967-7.417 3.967 1.481-8.279-6.064-5.828 8.332-1.151z"/>
</defs>
<use  xlink:href="#star" x="10" y="0"  />
<use  xlink:href="#star" x="35" y="0"  />
<use  xlink:href="#star" x="60" y="0"  /> 
<use  xlink:href="#star" x="85" y="0"  />
<use  xlink:href="#star" x="110" y="0"  />
</svg>
```

**P.S.**
**оригинал**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 23.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 800 800" style="enable-background:new 0 0 800 800;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:#000000;}
</style>
<g>
 <path class="st0" d="M496.2,800H303.8v-18c0-157.6-128.2-285.8-285.8-285.8H0V303.8h18c157.6,0,285.8-128.2,285.8-285.8V0h192.3v18
  c0,157.6,128.2,285.8,285.8,285.8h18v192.4h-18c-157.6,0-285.8,128.2-285.8,285.8V800z M339.4,764h121.3
  c9-163.1,140.2-294.3,303.3-303.3V339.4c-163.2-9-294.3-140.2-303.3-303.3H339.4c-9,163.2-140.2,294.3-303.3,303.3v121.3
  C199.2,469.7,330.3,600.8,339.4,764z M400,621.6l-15.9-30.4c-39.4-75.3-100-135.8-175.2-175.2l-30.5-16l30.5-16
  c75.2-39.3,135.8-99.9,175.2-175.2l15.9-30.5l16,30.5c39.4,75.2,100,135.8,175.2,175.2l30.5,16l-30.5,16
  c-75.2,39.4-135.8,100-175.2,175.2L400,621.6z M253.6,400c59.7,36.8,109.5,86.7,146.4,146.4c36.8-59.7,86.7-109.6,146.4-146.4
  c-59.7-36.8-109.6-86.7-146.4-146.4C363.1,313.3,313.3,363.2,253.6,400z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="150" height="24" viewBox="60 0 24 24">
<style type="text/css">
 .st1{fill:#000000;}
</style>
<defs>
<g>
<path id="star" class="st1"  d="M496.2,800H303.8v-18c0-157.6-128.2-285.8-285.8-285.8H0V303.8h18c157.6,0,285.8-128.2,285.8-285.8V0h192.3v18
  c0,157.6,128.2,285.8,285.8,285.8h18v192.4h-18c-157.6,0-285.8,128.2-285.8,285.8V800z M339.4,764h121.3
  c9-163.1,140.2-294.3,303.3-303.3V339.4c-163.2-9-294.3-140.2-303.3-303.3H339.4c-9,163.2-140.2,294.3-303.3,303.3v121.3
  C199.2,469.7,330.3,600.8,339.4,764z M400,621.6l-15.9-30.4c-39.4-75.3-100-135.8-175.2-175.2l-30.5-16l30.5-16
  c75.2-39.3,135.8-99.9,175.2-175.2l15.9-30.5l16,30.5c39.4,75.2,100,135.8,175.2,175.2l30.5,16l-30.5,16
  c-75.2,39.4-135.8,100-175.2,175.2L400,621.6z M253.6,400c59.7,36.8,109.5,86.7,146.4,146.4c36.8-59.7,86.7-109.6,146.4-146.4
  c-59.7-36.8-109.6-86.7-146.4-146.4C363.1,313.3,313.3,363.2,253.6,400z"/>
</g>
</defs>
<use  xlink:href="#star" x="0" y="0"  />
<use  xlink:href="#star" x="30" y="0"  />
<use  xlink:href="#star" x="60" y="0"  />
<use  xlink:href="#star" x="90" y="0"  />
<use  xlink:href="#star" x="120" y="0"  />
</svg>
```

Comment: Добавлен [второй ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1110724/28748) на вторую часть вопроса после слов **P.S.
оригинал**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если элемент svg не видно, надо в первую очередь загрузить файл в векторный редактор и  это поможет увидеть причину

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь стало понятно, почему не был виден элемент,- он во-первых находится вне документа SVG и намного больше его по размерам 800 x 800px.

Чтобы добавить этот элемент в существующий документ SVG нужно его уменьшить

`800 / 24 = 33,33 раза` Будем уменьшать в 34 раза, чтобы были минимальные отступы от краев документа.

Уменьшение делается с помощью команды `transform="scale(0.029)"`

`1 / 34 = 0.029`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="120" height="24" viewBox="60 0 24 24" style="border:1px solid" >
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:#000000;}
</style>
<defs>
<path id="star" class="st0" transform="scale(0.029)" d="M800,318.1C624.6,318.1,481.9,175.4,481.9,0h-30.4H348.5h-30.4c0,175.4-142.7,318.1-318.1,318.1v30.4
 c0,0,0,0,0,0v133.3c175.4,0,318.1,142.7,318.1,318.1h30.4h102.9h30.4c0-175.4,142.7-318.1,318.1-318.1v-30.4c0,0,0,0,0,0V318.1z
  M400,590.8C357.3,509.5,290.5,442.7,209.2,400c81.3-42.7,148.1-109.5,190.8-190.8c42.7,81.3,109.5,148.1,190.8,190.8
 C509.5,442.7,442.7,509.5,400,590.8z"/>
</defs>
<use  xlink:href="#star" x="15" y="0"  />
<use  xlink:href="#star" x="45" y="0"  />
</svg>
```

Расстояние между элементами можно изменять с помощью параметра `x=45` в команде `<use>`

**Update**

Можно и без векторного редактора обойтись, чтобы узнать положение и размеры объекта SVG, использовав метод JS `getBBox()`

```
let bb = star.getBBox();
 console.log(bb.width);
 console.log(bb.height);
```

```js
let bb = star.getBBox();
 console.log(bb.width);
 console.log(bb.height);
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="120" height="24" viewBox="60 0 24 24"  >
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:#000000;}
</style>
<defs>
<path id="star" class="st0" transform="scale(0.029)" d="M800,318.1C624.6,318.1,481.9,175.4,481.9,0h-30.4H348.5h-30.4c0,175.4-142.7,318.1-318.1,318.1v30.4
 c0,0,0,0,0,0v133.3c175.4,0,318.1,142.7,318.1,318.1h30.4h102.9h30.4c0-175.4,142.7-318.1,318.1-318.1v-30.4c0,0,0,0,0,0V318.1z
  M400,590.8C357.3,509.5,290.5,442.7,209.2,400c81.3-42.7,148.1-109.5,190.8-190.8c42.7,81.3,109.5,148.1,190.8,190.8
 C509.5,442.7,442.7,509.5,400,590.8z"/>
</defs>
<use  xlink:href="#star" x="15" y="0"  />
<use  xlink:href="#star" x="45" y="0"  />
</svg>
```

Comment: подскажите, почему не работает теперь для такого же svg, только другого цвета? добавил в вопрос

Comment: @word прочитайте мой ответ внимательно, как велся расчет. Вы взяли другой объект SVG, с другими размерами, поэтому и не работает. Нужно для этого примера снова всё расчитать Цвет тут ни при чём

Comment: только увидел, нужно scale добавить, пропустил случайно, благодарю

Comment: @word так не принято, когда уже дан ответ, менять вопрос, потому что в этом случае ответы не актуальны и выглядят глупо )))

Comment: вернул добавленный вариант

Comment: @word я имел ввиду ваш первый вариант вопроса, на который мы отвечали. Вот его надо вернуть на место. А другие варианты, нужно опять задавать в новом вопросе. Хотя из наших ответов, наверное можно разобраться, как делать, как считать, всё же очень подробно написано

Comment: не понял, а что не так в моём первоначальном вопросе?

Answer (score 3):

Примерно так

Судя по первой координате M800 я предположил что иконка находится далеко за пределами viewBox и я его поставил 0 0 800 800 и потом делал смещение на 100

Ну  и разумеется випилил лишнее и код стал короче

В SVG2:0 xlink - deprecated

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 4400 800" width="300">
<defs>
  <path id="star"  d="M800,318.1C624.6,318.1,481.9,175.4,481.9,0h-30.4H348.5h-30.4c0,175.4-142.7,318.1-318.1,318.1v30.4c0,0,0,0,0,0v133.3c175.4,0,318.1,142.7,318.1,318.1h30.4h102.9h30.4c0-175.4,142.7-318.1,318.1-318.1v-30.4c0,0,0,0,0,0V318.1zM400,590.8C357.3,509.5,290.5,442.7,209.2,400c81.3-42.7,148.1-109.5,190.8-190.8c42.7,81.3,109.5,148.1,190.8,190.8
 C509.5,442.7,442.7,509.5,400,590.8z" fill="#000"/></defs>

  <use href="#star" x="0" y="0" width="100px" />
  <use href="#star" x="900" y="0" width="100px" />
  <use href="#star" x="1800" y="0" width="100px" />
  <use href="#star" x="2700" y="0" width="100px" />
  <use href="#star" x="3600" y="0" width="100px" />
</svg>
```

Comment: а подскажите пожалуйста, из-за чего не показывался svg? что вы поправили?

Comment: @MaximLensky дополнение - `href` safari IOS не понимает, только `xlink:href` Вот чтобы была кроссбраузерность, многие уже сейчас пишут двойное обозначение в одной строке - `href="#star"   xlink:href="#star"` и это работает везде

Answer (score 1):

### Ответ на 2-ой пример кода из вопроса ниже  "P.S. оригинал"

Посмотрите, как выглядит ваш код в векторном редакторе

Ошибка та же, что и в первой части вопроса. Вы рисуете свою фигуру вне svg документа (это серый прямоугольник) и не в том масштабе, какой вам нужен будет на выходе.

Поэтому, когда вы копируете код SVG Фигуры в код SVG документа, вы не увидите фигуру, потому что она находится вне документа SVG и намного больше его.

Правильнее будет сразу рисовать  внутри svg документа (серый прямоугольник на рисунке)
Для этого задайте нужный размер документа внутри векторного редактора, увеличьте масштаб отображения в векторном редакторе, если размер маленький и **рисуйте фигуру внутри этого прямоугольника**

Тогда на выходе вы получите код, который будет сразу же отображаться.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конечно, я сейчас сделаю манипуляции для уменьшения svg фигуры и она попадет в SVG документ.

Размер вашей фигуры `800 х 800px`, поэтому, как и в первом ответе уменьшаем фигуру

`<path id="star" class="st1" transform="scale(0.029)"`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="150" height="24" viewBox="60 0 24 24">
<style type="text/css">
 .st1{fill:red;}
</style>
<defs>
<g>
<path id="star" class="st1" transform="scale(0.029)" d="M496.2,800H303.8v-18c0-157.6-128.2-285.8-285.8-285.8H0V303.8h18c157.6,0,285.8-128.2,285.8-285.8V0h192.3v18
  c0,157.6,128.2,285.8,285.8,285.8h18v192.4h-18c-157.6,0-285.8,128.2-285.8,285.8V800z M339.4,764h121.3
  c9-163.1,140.2-294.3,303.3-303.3V339.4c-163.2-9-294.3-140.2-303.3-303.3H339.4c-9,163.2-140.2,294.3-303.3,303.3v121.3
  C199.2,469.7,330.3,600.8,339.4,764z M400,621.6l-15.9-30.4c-39.4-75.3-100-135.8-175.2-175.2l-30.5-16l30.5-16
  c75.2-39.3,135.8-99.9,175.2-175.2l15.9-30.5l16,30.5c39.4,75.2,100,135.8,175.2,175.2l30.5,16l-30.5,16
  c-75.2,39.4-135.8,100-175.2,175.2L400,621.6z M253.6,400c59.7,36.8,109.5,86.7,146.4,146.4c36.8-59.7,86.7-109.6,146.4-146.4
  c-59.7-36.8-109.6-86.7-146.4-146.4C363.1,313.3,313.3,363.2,253.6,400z"/>
</g>
</defs>
<use  xlink:href="#star" x="0" y="0"  />
<use  xlink:href="#star" x="30" y="0"  />
<use  xlink:href="#star" x="60" y="0"  />
<use  xlink:href="#star" x="90" y="0"  />
<use  xlink:href="#star" x="120" y="0"  />
</svg>
```